# Why does Array#each return an array with the same elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby, each, self, ruby-block

I'm learning the details of how `each` works in ruby, and I tried out the following line of code:

```
p [1,2,3,4,5].each { |element| el }
```

And the result is an array of

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Why is the return value of `each` the same array? Doesn't `each` just provide a method for iterating? Or is it just common practice for the `each` method to return the original value?

Comment: ruby API docs says `each {|item| block } → ary` so yes `each{block}`  method of `Array` class returns `self`

Comment: The reason is more of a convenience. It's basically a "free" operation for Ruby to return the original array (otherwise it would return `nil`). As a bonus it allows you to chain methods to further operate on the array if you want.

Comment: A small point: if no block is present, [1,2,3].each returns [1,2,3].to_enum (at least in Ruby 2.0).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns the [array] object it was invoked upon: the result of the block is *discarded*. Thus if there are no *icky* side-effects to the original array then nothing will have changed.

Perhaps you mean to use `map`?

```
p [1,2,3,4,5].map { |i| i*i }
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to use map, just wondering why the return value was the same array. But you have confirmed that it just returns the same object

Answer (score 6):

If you want, for some reason, to suppress the output (for example debugging in console) here is how you can achive that

```
  [1,2,3,4,5].each do |nr|
    puts nr.inspect
  end;nil
```

Comment: OMG `end;nil` IS WHAT I'VE BEEN SEARCHING FOR MY WHOLE LIFE!!!

Comment: Basically `end;nil` is the same as just a `return nil` in the next line after `end`. The `return` can be omitted, as ruby methods always return the last statement.

Comment: Sure, this makes no sense in real code. But a lot of times the return messes up the console. Like in my example where you wan to see the output.

Answer (score 4):

#### Array#each

The block form of [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) returns the original Array object. You generally use #each when you want to *do* something with each element of an array inside the block. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each { |element| puts element }
```

This will print out each element, but returns the *original* array. You can verify this with:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array.each { |element| element }.object_id === array.object_id
=> true
```

#### Array#map

If you want to return a *new* array, you want to use [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) or one of its synonyms. The block form of #map returns a different Array object. For example:

```
array.object_id
=> 25659920
array.map { |element| element }.object_id
=> 20546920
array.map { |element| element }.object_id === array.object_id
=> false
```

You will generally want to use #map when you want to operate on a modified version of the original array, while leaving the original unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

All methods return something. Even if it's just a `nil` object, it returns something.

It may as well return the original object rather than return `nil`.

Comment: Right, I was just expecting it to be Nil, though I should have read the docs a little more carefully.