# Using gsub to replace String with Symbols in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that is reading in RSS feeds using the simple_feed gem.  However, some of the feeds don't read in correctly - namely, some of the titles have:

```
`&#x2018;`
```

or

```
`&#x2019;`
```

instead of: "

My titles read in as:

```
i.title
```

and I was thinking that gsub can fix this easily, but I was have trouble making it work.  I tried:

```
i.title.gsub(%r[&#x2018;]/, '"')
```

which I'm not even sure would work, but it commented out the line after the `#`.

Then I tried:

```
i.title.gsub(%r["&#x2018;"]/, '*')
```

which results in:

```
C:/Sites/foo/app/views/bar/show.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected ','
...( i.title.gsub(%r["&#x2018;"]/, '*') )
```

I haven't really used gsub before, I was trying to work off [these examples](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub).  Can something please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried doing a straight substitution instead of using a regex: `i.title.gsub("&#x2018;",'"')

Comment: No, how does that work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
i.title.gsub("&#x2018;", '"')
```

or with

```
i.title.gsub(/&#x2018;/, '"')
```

Comment: Thanks Rorra, that works.  I've found that sometimes &#x2019; also appears, so I have multiple strings to look for (I edited my question - I had a typo before where I said &#x2018; or &#x2018; appears instead of saying &#x2018; or &#x2019; appears).  How do I change the syntax to reflect this?

Comment: Sorry, I should have searched first.  I found this answer and just ended up adding another .gsub (ie str.gsub.gsub) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132492/ruby-multiple-string-replacement